# How big can circle of protection be for sadhna in the cremation grounds?

Tags: tantra, agamas, kapalika

It is said that evil forces in the cremation ground will attack if you dont make a circle for protection. But how big can it be?

Is 3-4 metre circle effective?

[image]

Comment: For which sadhana? Question is unclear. Also IIRC cremation ground is for prayoga and not for sadhana. There is a difference. But I may be wrong.

Comment: There are many Sadhanas mentioned in Tantras which are required to be done on cremation grounds. For example for any Krur Karmas Sadhana place is always Samshana @TheLittleNaruto